# Getting environment variable using Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have an update version of a file that I need to provide to the user,

I have given the user the choice to install the original software wherever they want,

So now to do the update I need the PATH system variable to know where they installed the software,

I have the following code:

```
[Setup]
#define path GetEnv('TEMPFILE')
DefaultGroupName={#path}

[Files]
Source: "E:\folder \license.exe"; DestDir: "{app}\temp\installation_files\"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

But the code gives me an error during installation!

Does someone know why?

Maybe i can do this differently,

Can someone explain to me hoe this function works:

```
function GetEnv(const EnvVar: String): String;
```

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. You have no way of knowing that the first `license.exe` you find on the PATH is yours. What happens if you're not the only person in the world who distributed a `license.exe`, and it happens to be located somewhere in the PATH before yours? Your installation "updates it" and breaks some other (possibly crucial to the user) application. If you're going to be distributing updates to your app, it should be recording its installed folder in the registry during the original installation, and then future updates can locate it by reading that registry value.

Comment: Apologies, PATH is just an example, i'm calling a different specific system variable that only has one path value.

Comment: "PATH" has a specific meaning in both Windows and Linux, so it's a poor example to use. If you need help, be specific and don't make things up as you go, please. We can't read your mind to know what you really mean instead. :-) It's still the wrong approach, IMO; there's a documented way to record your application's location in the Windows registry where future updates can find it, and Inno Setup supports doing so (I think it's even mentioned in the documentation somewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me can be found in the following link:

[Retrieve environment variable using RegQueryStringValue in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759345/retrieve-environment-variable-using-regquerystringvalue-in-inno-setup)