# Retrieve environment variable using RegQueryStringValue in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to retrieve an environment variable during installation using RegQueryStringValue,

I am using the following code

```
[Setup]
DefaultGroupName="{code:GetPath}"

[Code]
function GetPath(Value: String): String;
var
  OrigPath: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment', 'GCC', OrigPath) then
  Result := OrigPath;
end;
```

But the installer gives me an error during installation,

Can someone tell me why or what I can use instead?

Comment: What error? Why not just use `{%GCC}`? This method will get the actual current value rather than value stored in the registry for next load of Explorer. You may also want tp provide a default in case it doesn't exit.

Comment: When i use DefaultGroupName="{%GCC}", it says i should enter a folder name! even though the value is : C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe in system variable.

Comment: OK? what's the problem? `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` is a file name. `DefaultGroupName` is expecting a start menu group name. Using `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` for that makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you're actually trying to do, someone can help further.

Comment: I need to install an update in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google, which value is stored in PATH1. So i am using  DefaultGroupName="{%PATH1}". When i do that it tells me 'The folder name cannot include any of the following characters: /:*?"<>'.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were trying to use the GCC exectable path for that, or why you're trying to use it for the default Start menu group name. Maybe you mean `DefaultDirName`?

Comment: Well i release i cant use GCC, so im going to change the installer to C:\Program Files (x86)\Google directory instead!

Comment: Your comments and methodology are making no sense. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47441/discussion-between-deanna-and-user2333346)

Comment: And it has the system variable Name PATH1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of this question, you're trying to use `DefaultGroupName` instead of `DefaultDirName` which is causing the errors.